# A command before every bash command

Tags: command-line, bash, shell

Does anyone know a mean of putting a 'time' command before every command in a bash session?

Comment: so... you want to automatically prepend 'time' to every commandline?

Comment: yes, excaptly ... for performance mesuarament obviously

Comment: related http://superuser.com/questions/167283/is-there-a-way-to-preprocess-input-to-bash

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Sorry for the wrong answer before, I missunderstood your question.

To have the time added before every command that you execute on the shell you can do something like this

```
bind 'RETURN: "\e[1~time \e[4~\n"'
```

This will rebind the return key. Now every time you press return instead of writing a newline \n it will go to the beginning of the line, enter the text 'time' and a space, go to the end of the line and enter the newline \n thereby producing the desired effect.

If you don't want to sacrifice your Enter Key you could make a 'second' benchmark-enter Key like F12 by binding the command like this

```
bind '"\e[24~": "\e[1~time \e[4~\n"'
```

Now instead of replacing the return key you bound F12.

The background of all this is that bash uses GNU readline to read commands. So readline would be a good starting point for further command manipulation, etc.

Comment: +1 nice solution!  i like the idea of having a benchmarking enter key separate from the regular enter key.

Comment: that's a clever idea. [How can you generalize it to execute a user-defined function before every command?](http://superuser.com/questions/175799) I don't know how to combine bash code and a readline function in the same binding.

Comment: Will this not run in Mac? I ran the command in the terminal and my enter key doesn't seem to do anything now.

Comment: im trying to run the latter bind but it doesnt work in linux mint, bash.

Answer (score 9):

I realize that this is outside of the scope of this question but...

In `zsh` (which, is to my knowledge a super set of bash) if you set the following variable in your `.zshrc` file:

```
export REPORTTIME=5
```

Every command that takes longer than 5 seconds (I'm pretty sure) will display the output of `time`. All commands that complete more quickly don't. And in those cases one doesn't really care, so it's nice to not clutter things up. There are also a lot of other cool features in `zsh` that you might enjoy while you're at it.

Comment: Nice tip. While *zsh* surely has a superset of the functionality of *bash*, its syntax is not a superset of the syntax of *bash*, so it is not a “drop in” replacement.

Answer (score 1):

[PS1](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/) seems like the standard way to do something like this.

Comment: It modifies the display, not the actual executed command.

Comment: @grawity Right - but it would get you exactly what you want ... the time prepended to every line.

Comment: Which is completely different from what `time` does (it measures how long did it take for a command to execute).

Comment: @grawity, I guess you're right -- you'd have to do the subtraction yourself. Looks like @Jrobert had the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

Include \t in your prompt string.  It will include the time in your prompt at the point where you include it.  See:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/

Comment: That's the current time at the time the prompt is generated, not the time it took to execute the previous command.

Comment: True; and the difference between that and the next prompt's current time is the run-time (minus typing time, of course - pasting is your friend here).  No key reassignments necessary.