# bash command history update before execution of command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, history

Bash's command history is great, especially it is useful when adding the `history -a` command to the COMMAND_PROMPT.

However, I'm wondering if there is a way to log the commands to a file as soon as the Return key is pressed, e.g. before starting the command and not on completion of the command (using the COMMAND_PROMPT option would save the command once the prompt is there again).

I read about auditing programs like snoopy and session recorder like script but I thought they're already too complex for the simple question I have. I guess that deactivating that script logs all the output of the command would lead already in the right direction but isn't there a quicker way to solve that probelm?

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: @Jon there is no COMMAND_PROMPT. i think you mean PROMPT_COMMAND.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/167283/is-there-a-way-to-preprocess-input-to-bash

Answer (score 1):

The DEBUG trap is executed before each command. You could set up a trap and in that do your logging.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much. There is a little bit of fine tuning still necessary but it looks very promising.