# REPORTTIME for Bash

Tags: bash, time, zsh

[Zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) has an ingenious feature that automatically prints timing statistics for commands taking longer than `$REPORTTIME` to execute. Think of it as automatically executing a pipeline through `time` as needed.

From the Zsh Manual:

```
REPORTTIME
    If nonzero, commands whose combined user and system execution times
    (measured in seconds) are greater than this value have timing statistics
    printed for them.
```

Does there exist a similar feature, or set of scripts that enables similar behaviour, for Bash?

Comment: One clever hack is mentioned in [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/117227/a-command-before-every-bash-command). Another way is to use [something like zsh's `preexec`](http://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have an implementation of it, here: https://github.com/mstormo/reporttime

Clone the Git repo, and simply source the reporttime.bash script. Also allows you to put the timing components into your Bash prompt directly, instead of having it reported on a separate line.