# Can't run 'rails' inside Tmux session in Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, tmux, ruby

I just tried `rails` inside a `tmux` session in `iTerm2` and it returns as

```
-bash: /usr/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I can run `rails` outside of `tmux` . I am using Mac OSX. I've installed Ruby via RVM . Here's the output of `ruby -v`

```
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

and `which ruby`

```
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
```

It's the same output for both inside `tmux` and normal bash shell.

Here's my `~/.tmux.conf`

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

How am I able to run `rails` inside the `tmux` session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the `bash` session inside `tmux` is running as an interactive shell; the `-i` option to `bash` will start it in this mode. If I recall correctly, the RVM script runs from `.bashrc`, which is only executed for interactive shells; since it's the RVM script which adds `~/.rvm/...` to your path, if it's not running, then bash will not be looking in the right place for the Ruby interpreter.

Comment: you mean adding `-i` option to `tmux new -s new-tmux` in the bash shell ? sorry. I am new to these stuff.

Comment: I don't use Tmux on a regular basis, so can't give as good advice here as I like. But based on the testing I've just done, you'd need to add `set-option -g default-command "/bin/bash -i"` as a line in your `~/.tmux.conf` to ensure that bash starts in interactive mode.

Comment: It seems working now. But I see a couple of `bash: preexec_invoke_exec: command not found` lines and it seems annoying and `bash` becomes like `bash-3.2$` . Here's the [pic](http://i.imgur.com/Hf73xgC.png). Any ways to fix it ?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but [this](http://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command) has some more information on the `preexec_invoke_exec` hook, which may be of help.