# How to execute a function in bash or zsh on every letter being typed into prompt?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, zsh, tmux

I know about **preexec()** hooks for zsh and the way this can be achieved in bash. ( [link](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command) )

But can i get the **current input** while still typing?

The idea behind this question is the following:

in order to allow quicker learning of commands,arguments and shortcuts i want to search the command being typed in a "database" providing "help / good-to-know / shortcut" hints and show these in another session with screen/tmux while typing in the other.

Is it possible to check for the current command being typed? If it does not work on every keystroke a timer loop might work aswell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can only answer for `zsh`, where this can be done, yes.

First, there are already some widgets for *incremental completion*. The first one is apparently that by Y. Fujii. Although [its site](http://mimosa-pudica.net/zsh-incremental.html) is in Japanese, you can easily figure out without speaking that language, how it works and how to use it.
[Auto-fu](https://github.com/hchbaw/auto-fu.zsh) is an extension of the original script.

So far the references. In `zsh` the *zsh line editor* (`zle`) is in charge of the interactive use of the command line. Apart from a lot of other variables provided to widgets (see `man zshzle`), these are of interest to you as you want to capture the *current command line*:

> **$BUFFER**:
>                The  entire  contents  of the edit buffer.
>
> **$LBUFFER**:
>                The part of the buffer that lies to the left of the cursor position.
>
> **$RBUFFER**:
>                The part of the buffer that lies to the right of the cursor position.

These variables are writable, what will alter the current command line!

To capture each keystroke, you can modify the widget `self-insert` which is executed (by default) for every keystroke except `LF` or `CR`. Here is an example, which does nothing very useful, but appends for every keystroke a dot to `$RBUFFER` -- just to illustrate how this works:

```
function self-insert() {
  RBUFFER+="."
  # execute some other command, but ensure they don't produce any output.
  zle .self-insert
  }
zle -N self-insert
```

`.self-insert` is the built-in widget, so we don't run into an infinity loop.

So, you either can start from scratch or start from Fujii's script and modify it. One benefit of the latter is, that it also does some handling of deleting keystrokes which I neglected here.

Comment: thanks for your awesome answer - this is exactly what i was looking for. now i can check $BUFFER on keystroke and decide which helpfile to show in my second terminal. yeah! :)

Comment: @nifr: You're welcome... btw. it's _zsh_ that's awesome `;)`

Answer (score 2):

For Bash you can create following `test.sh` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ARRAY=('1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '0' '-' '=' 'BACKSPACE' ''
'q' 'w' 'e' 'r' 't' 'y' 'u' 'i' 'o' 'p' '[' ']' 'NEWLINE' '' 
'a' 's' 'd' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'j' 'k' 'l' ';' "'" '' '' '' 'z' 'x' 'c' 
'v' 'b' 'n' 'm' '0' ',' '.' '/' '' '' 'SPACE')

while read row 
do
    if [[ "$row" == *press* ]]
    then
        index=$((${row/key press   /}-10))
        if [[ "${ARRAY[$index]}" == 'NEWLINE' ]] 
        then
                printf "\n"
        elif [[ "${ARRAY[$index]}" == 'BACKSPACE' ]] 
        then
            echo  -ne "\b \b"
        elif [[ "${ARRAY[$index]}" == 'SPACE' ]] 
        then
            printf " "
        else
            printf "%s" "${ARRAY[$index]}"
        fi
    fi
done
```

It's a simple script that is receiveing some of keyboard codes and print them in the screen. Now pass keyboard codes to it:

```
$ stdbuf -o0 xinput test 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard' | bash test.sh
```

Now if you type in another terminal, it should receive key values. I don't know if there is any clever way to map key codes to their ASCII values so I'm just doing a simple mapping. You can improve this code to react to other keys as well. Note however that script will receive all keyboard input, not only passed to one given terminal.

As for task itself (checking for the current command being typed) you can use `compgen -c` to generate list of possible completions based on passed argument:

```
 $ compgen -c 'ls' | head -1
 ls
 $ compgen -c 'lsp' | head -1
 lspci
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer :) sadly i wasnt able to verify it is working as there seems to be no stdbuf in cygwin ( which i'm forced to use at work currently ). Definitely going to try it out this weekend.

Comment: @nifr: did you try it out?  can you post whether it worked?