# Terminal beep after inactivity

Tags: macos, terminal, alert

I'd like to be able to set an inactivity timer for a terminal window  (OSX) - so if I hadn't typed anything for n minutes it would give a 'beep/alert/run script' - is there a as-yet-unfound-by-me-terminal command/command-line-fu that does this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is this for something like keeping an ssh session alive?

Comment: Actually to remind me that I have open sessions open and that I should either be working on them or close them... I suspose you could use to keep a session alive...

Answer (score 2):

### Inactivity timer

Running a delayed command is simple: `sleep <sleep time>; run_a_command`

Wrapping that in start/stop timer functions:

```
INACTIVITY_TIME='5m'
INACTIVITY_CMD='echo -ne \a'
function inactivity-start-timer () {
    (sleep "$INACTIVITY_TIME"; $INACTIVITY_CMD) &
    INACTIVITY_PID=$!
    disown
}

function inactivity-stop-timer () {
    kill $INACTIVITY_PID > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

You can add that your shell rc file. Now you need to run `inactivity-start-timer` before every prompt and `inactivity-stop-timer` before every command execution. (You don't want a beep if the command takes too long, do you?) Also this assumes you have the system bell on, otherwise put another command into `INACTIVITY_CMD`.

### Bash

I am guessing you use bash? In that case there is [PROMPT_COMMAND](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) to run a command before every prompt. But nothing built-in to run before every command execution. There is a known trick to get that [here](https://superuser.com/a/175802/197309). So add this also to your .bashrc:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=inactivity-start-timer

preexec () {
    inactivity-stop-timer
}

preexec_invoke_exec () {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # do nothing if completing
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return # don't cause a preexec for $PROMPT_COMMAND
 local this_command=`history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g"`;
 preexec "$this_command"
}
trap 'preexec_invoke_exec' DEBUG
```

### Zsh

If you use zsh on the other hand its [simpler](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions):

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd inactivity-start-timer
add-zsh-hook preexec inactivity-stop-timer
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) has [silence](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Silence.html) monitoring, and [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) does something similar with the [monitor-silence](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1) command.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was an interesting thing to figure out. I don't have BSD, so I solved
the problem on Linux. There is something like inotify for BSD, called 
kqueue(2), but I don't know if there are convenient monitor tools like 
`inotifywait` for that kernel fascility.

The idea is to monitor the standard output of a terminal which is a file.

```
#!/bin/bash
myterm=/dev/`ps -o tty= | head -n1`
if [ $# -eq 0 ] && [ -r $myterm ] && [ ! -d $myterm ]; then
    terminal=$myterm
else
    terminal=${1:-/dev/pts/1}
fi

function time_out {
    echo timeout
    loop=false
}

loop=true
timeout=4

while $loop; do
    inotifywait $terminal -qq -t $timeout -e MODIFY || time_out
done
```