# Is there a way to open non-runnable files directly from CLI

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, default-settings

Let's say I have file without execution permission. Now a quick way to open such a file over the `CLI` is to use `xdg-open` which uses the system default to open a specific file.

Is it now possible to open files without running permission directly without stating `xdg-open`?

For example:

```
./test.pdf
```

should then open the viewer in case that file doesn't have excecution permission.

Comment: I know that with `oh-my-zsh` you can use `~/directory` similarly to `cd ~/directory`, so... perhaps.

Comment: Hm, yes maybe this would depend on the terminal used. In this case it would be great to get an answer working for either gnome-terminal or tcsh. Of course bonus points for a terminal independent solution. (Some fancy alias solution maybe I don't know about maybe)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put; no.

Files do not 'run', especially not PDF files. The closest you can get is to replace xdg-open with the specific name of the program you want to have started:

```
evince ./file.pdf
```

The xdg-open command simplifies this, though, by making use of configured mime types.

Going a bit further, bash scripts work like this because they contain a shebang declaration, which tells the system which program to use to open it (for bash scripts it'd be the bash interpreter). PDFs do not contain this information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this in some shells. Compare [*Does bash have a hook that is run before executing a command?*](https://superuser.com/q/175799/432690)

This link may not be the best because in `bash` it's not as easy as you wish. However it mentions `preexec` from `zsh`. My point is: in some shells you can analyze the command line in your own way and take your own actions.

Comment: I think that's what I was looking for. I'll try to make if work this week. I think this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099966/use-preexec-to-evaluate-entered-command) also has relevant information to achieve this.