# Print time after command has been entered

Tags: bash, bashrc

Is there a way to concatenate time after command has been entered? Example:

```bsh
user@machine$ date
11:50:41
Tue Jun 25 11:50:41 EEST 2019
```

Current workaround is to add `\t\n` to PS1 before the username but that is not quite what I want to achieve, as it might lie, especially when the processing takes time and has a lot of output, e.g. when apt is run after a hiatus.

One idea I had was to capture the input with `read` but execute it after the time was printed. One downside is the command is then entered/printed second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trap 'date +%T' DEBUG
```

Solution taken from answers to this question: [*Does bash have a hook that is run before executing a command?*](https://superuser.com/q/175799/432690).

Comment: Thank you, Kamil! The link you posted was helpful. Found [Bash-preexec](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec) through that but your solution is more elegant.