# If ANY command took more than 20 seconds to finish, run an arbitrary script

Tags: macos, bash

I'd love to "wrap" *any* command I type, such that, if it took more than 20 seconds to complete, I can run a notify command.

Something like:

```
$ sleep 30
```

Would conceptually do something like:

```
elapsed=real_time $(sleep 30);
if [ $elapsed > 20 ];
 say "Done";
fi
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Research material: [*Does bash have a hook that is run before executing a command?*](https://superuser.com/q/175799/432690) I think if you make the "after" and "before" solutions work together then you will be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `SIGALRM` to fire after a specific amout of time, and cancel it when all your jobs have finished. This is tricky to do in pure shell script, though. The [`timeout`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) command in GNU coreutils is a convenient and reasonably user-friendly starting point.

If you want this to be integrated into your interactive shell, you might be able to put it in a `DEBUG` trap. Perhaps see https://askubuntu.com/a/409801/25077

Answer (score 1):

If you have an idea that you're going to be running a long-running command, you can do something like:

```
sleep 30 && say "hi"
```

You don't want to manually add this for every command, but then again you really should know the difference between a quick `ls` command and a longer run `brew install`, `make`, etc, that you can expect to run for a while.