# Automatically add bits before and after a bash command

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to be able to enter `foo` and have bash automatically convert it to `time foo && notify-send "PLAYBOOK COMPLETE"`?

I'd specifically like this to apply only to `ansible-playbook` commands (for those not familiar with Ansible, any number of options, arguments etc. might follow `ansible-playbook` so a simple alias probably won't do the trick) so that I get notified when a long playbook has finished.

[A command before every bash command](https://superuser.com/questions/117227/a-command-before-every-bash-command) looked promising, but unfortunately didn't work correctly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a shell function:

```
function ansible-playbook { time command ansible-playbook "$@" && notify-send "PLAYBOOK COMPLETE"; }
```

or

```
ansible-playbook () { time command ansible-playbook "$@" && notify-send "PLAYBOOK COMPLETE"; }
```

The latter form is the POSIX way to define a function but `ansible-playbook` alias (if any) may interfere. The former form is immune but not portable. If there is no alias and you're using Bash then either form will work.

Or you can write a wrapper script that works in a similar way. If you name it `ansible-playbook` then make sure it calls the *real* `ansible-playbook`, not itself. In the above function the word `command` prevents calling the function itself in an infinite loop.

Comment: Many thanks for this Kamil! Does this need to go in a bashrc file or something like that?

Comment: @Sam If you want the function to be automatically defined for Bash then yes, in `~/.bashrc`. A properly managed wrapper script will work with any shell.